# How to use Django iterator in this case

Tags: django, iterator, django-queryset

I want to show 20 reviews per page on my website.

Unfortunately whole reviews count is about 260,000, It takes 3~4sec to show at page 10,000~

I used to use queryset like this:

```
reviews = Review.objects.all()[(page_num-1)*20:20*page_num]
.
.
.

obj['reviews'] = reviews
```

Now I think using iterator(chunk_size=) is better than upper one for efficiency.

But I dont know how to use iterator() properly.

I definitely need your helps

Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Django pagination:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/

```
p = Paginator(objects, 20)
>>> p.count
20*N
>>> p.num_pages
N
page1 = p.page(1)
page2 = p.page(2)
...
pageN = p.page(n)
```

Comment: I already checked Paginator, but it showed me same performance like Review.objects.all()[(page_num-1)*20:20*page_num].

Just give me the usage example of iterator() plz...

Comment: If you really want to use chunk size here you go https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10599/